# Help with homework proof Probability

Tags: probability

I have two proofs I need to finish for my homework. I'm not asking for the entire solution. I'm just a little unsure on where exactly to start.

1.
For the mutually exclusive and exhaustive events $B_1,...,B_n$ with probability $P(B_i)>0$, for all $i=1,...,n$ Show that for any event A it has the probability.

$P(A)= \sum_{i=1} ^n P(A|B_i)P(B_i)$

I would like to know if that specific probability has a name, I looked up Bayes formula but it doesn't seem quite right. Also any help on getting started would be appreciated.

Comment: You should post these as two separate questions.

Comment: Wouldn't that be considered spam?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't consider it spam! Unrelated questions shouldn't be posted together, in general; if they're closely related, then sure, but these are rather different.

Comment: Okay I will do that then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

To prove it, you need two steps:

1. $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\&B)$
2. $A=\sqcup_i A\&B_i$ (disjoint union)

Comment: Thanks you. This should help me get through it